Android annoying Widget touch down press effect
I have a one plus Nord 4 Android phone with oxygenOS 14.1
I can't seem to find a way to remove the touch animation effect from widgets when interacting with them.
I managed to do on my old phone in the accessibility settings.
But can't find anything related on my new phone.
Does anyone experience the same problem or know a solution to disable this effect on widgets?
